# error: cannot invoke 'onNext' with an argument list of type '(String)' RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Why is the following RxSwift code not compiling and how do I solve the problem? This line `observer.onNext("test123")` is the problem.

```
final class TestA<String>: ObservableType {

    typealias E = String

    private let _observable: Observable<String>

    init() {
        _observable = Observable<String>.create { observer -> Disposable in
            print("mark 1")
            observer.onNext("test123")
            observer.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

    func subscribe<O>(_ observer: O) -> Disposable where O : ObserverType, O.E == E {
        return _observable.subscribe(observer)
    }
}

let observable = TestA<String>()
print("mark 2")
observable.subscribe(onNext: { element in
    print(element)
})
```

I am testing in the playground and get the following error:

> Playground execution failed:
>
> error: Introduction.xcplaygroundpage:25:26: error: cannot invoke 'onNext' > with an argument list of type '(String)'
>                   observer.onNext("test123")
>                            ^
>
> Introduction.xcplaygroundpage:25:26: note: expected an argument list of > type '(String)'
>                   observer.onNext("test123")
>                            ^

One of the reasons behind this setup with the class is that I want to pass in the dependencies with constructor injection and use them in the create closure in order to avoid having to capture self. I also want to avoid having all those `Observable.create`s in the wild and have a more OOP approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swift compiler was not helpful with this error...

The problem here is that, when declaring `TestA`, you override the name `String` to represent the generic parameter for `TestA`. It is then an error to sent a `Swift.String` as a parameter to an observer expecting a `TestA.String`, which could be anything.

You can fix the issue with removing the unused generic parameter (`final class TestA: ObservableType { ...`), or taking the value sent to `onNext` as a parameter to the init, depending on the use case.

```
final class TestA<Element>: ObservableType {

    typealias E = Element

    private let _observable: Observable<Element>

    init(_ value: Element) {
        _observable = Observable<Element>.create { observer -> Disposable in
            print("mark 1")
            observer.onNext(value)
            observer.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

    func subscribe<O>(_ observer: O) -> Disposable where O : ObserverType, O.E == E {
        return _observable.subscribe(observer)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. the solution _removing the unused generic parameter_ is the one that works for my use case.